# Is it possible to store Wordpress Templates in "theme/template" instead of putting them in the main directory of the theme?

Tags: wordpress

A site I work on has a ton of different templates. I'm just trying to keep things organized.  I'd like to put all the non-standard templates (IE not single.php, page.php, etc) into their own directory.

Is this common? Doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I believe it's possible.  According to [this post](http://nacin.com/2012/03/29/page-templates-in-subdirectories-new-in-wordpress-3-4/) by Andrew Nacin, WordPress will look for template files in the root folder of the theme **and** in any (single) subfolder that is one level deep.

So, for example, let's say you have a ton of taxonomy template files like:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
```

... And they're cluttering up your root folder of your theme... You can just throw them into a subfolder (the name shouldn't matter) such as `templates_taxonomies/taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` and WordPress should pick them up.

I haven't tested it though, so let me know if it works, I'd be curious to do that myself!

Have fun!

Comment: You know what? This does work.  I actually tried it prior to posting this and it didn't work but what I didn't realize is that when you do this, any page/post using that template needs to be told to use that template again. 

So you have to edit post/page, and then select the template again.